# Crystal Reports list of total distinct values

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008, crystal-reports-2010

Fairly new to Crystal Reports. If someone could point me in the right direction that would be great.

So I have a report that when run will produce the following:

```
ID  |   Car
-----------
1   |   Audi
2   |   Ford
3   |   Audi
4   |   Ford
5   |   Honda
```

In the report footer I want to produce a count of each distinct car. So for example I should have:

Audi - 2 
Ford - 2 
Honda - 1

Any help will be much appretiated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should give you the desired result:

- Create a subreport in the report footer
- Inside the subreport

  - Add the `Car`-field in the details-section
  - Add a group for the `Car`-field
  - Right Click the `Car`-field then select `Insert -> Summary`
  - Select the calculation option `Count`
  - Select the newly created group for the group level
  - Click OK
  - Move the new created summary-field beneath the groupname-field
  - Suppress all unneeded sections

Comment: Sorry deleted my previous comment. That's perfect and is working as expected. Many thanks :)